# SwiftUI View leaks in iOS 17

Tags: swiftui, view, memory-leaks, ios17

Seems View and its members do not deallocate after a presentation:

```swift
@main
struct ExampleApp: SwiftUI.App {
    @State var show = false

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Button("Present") { show = true }
                Text("First")
                    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $show) {
                        CheckSecond { show = false }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CheckSecond: View {
    private let log = LogDeinit()
    var action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second")
        Button("Back"){ action() }
    }
}

class LogDeinit {
    init(name: String) { print("init") }    
    deinit { print("deinit") }
}
```

Showing 'CheckSecond' back and forth causes 'init' in the console, but no 'deinit'. Memory map shows that 'LogDeinit' objects are referenced by single SwiftUI objects without any additional connection. In iOS 16 works correctly - 'deinit' is printed on each dismiss. Looks like a real leak.

Comment: You should file a Feedback with Apple

Comment: This is SwiftUI so you have to use structs instead of classes. It diffs these struct types in a memory efficient way and then it inits/updates/deinits the UIView classes automatically for us. So if you try to use a class you'll get leaks.

Comment: `@ObservedObject` is one of the main approaches fro updating the view. It requires `ObservableObject` protocol, which requires `AnyObject` - class types. So structures are not a solution there. Anyway, without classes Memory Graph shows the views as leaks.

Comment: Hey, this bug is unfixable. We just ran into the same issue at work, and after debugging for hours, the issue is because of `sheet(isPresented:)`, `sheet(item:)`, `fullCover(...)` etc. Any sort of `presentation` leaks the `View` objects that are presented and all the classes stored in those objects.

Comment: You are aware, that your code is not at all an idiomatic approach? I fear, there's a misconception about SwiftUI. IMHO, there should be no reference of the class instance kept by the SwiftUI system, _unless_ it's referenced in the body. In iOS 16 it seems it becomes a strong reference, bound to the lifetime of the underlying view, even it's not referenced. Maybe, this is correct behaviour. Now, in iOS 17 it seems, it becomes a strong reference and never gets deallocated. Definitely not good. I'm seeing _other_ issues with leaks as well. IMHO, using class instances this way is not recommended.

Comment: I recently also have very odd and frequent memory leaks related to sheet fullScreenCover and others. Maybe truly it is related to new iOS 17 version. I don't tested it on older iOS versions yet.

Comment: I don't take it using models with swiftui views is normal and using @StateObjects or ObservedObject is normal behavour. They shouldn't be structs but classes. I know they added macros and we don't need to use Published variable, but still it only adds some boilerplate for us. I don't buy it don't use classes

Comment: @DmitriyKurkin I'm facing similar issue. Do you have any updates?

Comment: @DmitriyKurkin I'm also facing a similar issue, although the closure I call is from a third-party library I have no control over. Have you found any workaround/solution?

Comment: Here is a post related to this issue with some additional details and a reference to a feedback I filed with Apple: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77098992/670119 Though, I haven’t heard back from Apple yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are some questions about workarounds. That is why I'm giving an answer to my own question:
It's already an iOS 17.0.3 and the issue is still there. We haven't found a better approach as use optional for the property and reset it in `onDisapear`

```
var reference: Service?
...

.onDisapear {
    reference = nil 
}
```

Of course, it could be wrapped in some property wrapper. But main idea is still the same

Answer (score -3):

Most already know that `@ObservedObject` is a leak because Apple said so in a WWDC video, e.g. this has a bad leak:

```
struct BadLeakView: View {
    @ObserverdObject var log = LogDeinit() // bad leak
```

However your example is a worse leak, because not only did you init an object in a View struct (SwiftUI keeps many copies of `View` structs so it can diff them) but you didn't even wrap it in any property wrapper, e.g. this is a very bad leak:

```
struct VeryBadLeakView: View {
    let log = LogDeinit() // very bad leak!
```

You can fix this with `@StateObject` however you should question if you even need an object, usually it's only when you need to do something asynchronous, like a Combine pipeline. Since we now have async/await usually you don't even need a `@StateObject` anymore since we have `.task` which is like a state object but as a simpler view modifier.

Comment: It’s not a leak. It just should be used properly. `@ObserverdObject var log = LogDeinit()` is incorrect, such kind of objects should be passed from the parent view, so in this case correct is `@ObserverdObject var log: LogDeinit`, no initialization inside self. Or like this if you want to init it inside `@StateObject var log = LogDeinit()`