# SwiftUI Sheet never releases object from memory

Tags: swift, swiftui, memory-leaks

I've found a very strange behaviour, sheet or fullScreenCover does not release objects that were passed to its item: parameter.

It **works well** and memory is releasing on **iOS 16** built with both Xcode 14 or 15. (simulators, devices)

Memory is **leaking** and NOT releasing on **iOS 17** built with Xcode 15. (simulators, device 17.0.2)

Did anybody find any info from Apple about this?

**UPDATE:** Apple has fixed this bug on iOS 17.2. So, we have this memory leak only on iOS 17.0...17.1.

```
struct CoordinatorView: View {
    @State var sheetVM: SheetVM?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            sheetVM = .init(dataGetter: {
                /// External injection needed here. This is just a simplified example
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                return "New title"
            })
        } label: {
            Text("Navigate")
        }
        .sheet(item: $sheetVM) { sheetVM in
            SheetView(viewModel: sheetVM)
        }
    }
}

final class SheetVM: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var title: String = "Title"
    private let dataGetter: () async throws -> String
    
    init(dataGetter: @escaping () async throws -> String) {
        self.dataGetter = dataGetter
        print("SheetVM init")
        Task { [refresh] in
            await refresh()
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    @Sendable
    private func refresh() async {
        do {
            title = try await dataGetter()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to get data")
        }
    }
    
    deinit { print("... SheetVM deinit") }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SheetVM
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(viewModel.title)")
    }
}

struct SheetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CoordinatorView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `item` is likely meant for a value type -- `ObservableObject`s shouldn't be kept in `@State` anyway and definitely shouldn't be created in actions like that. Instead, use a `struct` to pass the relevant information to the sheet and if absolutely necessary, use `@StateObject` to create/store a reference on the sheet itself

Comment: @jnpdx Show the documentation where Apple says we don't need to use class in sheets. It always worked and works great on iOS 14, 15, 16. What's the problem using State? I don't want to observe that class in that view and State is perfectly fine here, I was going to pass it further to another view which of course will observe it using ObservedObject. The State variable itself works great here, you can test. Question is only about memory releasing using sheet, I will appreciate if we can focus on it.

Comment: @jnpdx Btw, struct is also allocated in memory, and it is also a memory leak if struct is being caught by the .sheet and never releasing. And yes, I've tested also with the struct and it's also not releasing here on iOS 17. And the problem is might be deeper, the UIViewController under the hood of sheet is not being released, which is more likely if it's holding all the data when disappear.

Comment: I didn't say that "Apple says we don't need to use class in sheets". In general, though, `@State` is used for value types (not exclusively) and `@StateObject` is used to store `ObservableObject`. I was just trying to help. Good luck.

Comment: @jnpdx In general I can use State with class, it's not a mistake, I need that in this particular case. (show me where Apple says to not use class with State and why). Question is only about memory releasing using sheet, I will appreciate if we can focus on it.

Comment: "show me where Apple says to not use class with State and why" -- although I didn't say that specifically if you look at what my comment says (since I'm aware there are cases where it's useful to store a reference type), you can see in the documentation where Apple says "Use state as the single source of truth for a given value type that you store in a view hierarchy" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

Comment: @jnpdx Aoole did not say it's a mistake. Apple recommends it as a more general and straightforward use case. It's not a mistake. Ok. Wrap it into another class, put SheetVM under the Published property there, that wrapper class put as StateObject. Memory is still not released! Why are we discussing that State? It works perfect with class and I want to do so because understand how it works and I can do so, and even explained why (and it also makes the example code SIMPLER for stackoverflow). Question is only about memory releasing using sheet, I will appreciate if we can focus on it.

Comment: Probably a bug, State is leaking even with Observable right now. Report to Apple.

Comment: The suggestion about bug reporting makes sense.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a work around for this problem

Comment: @malhal I edited my question to explicitly show what I've explained earlier. ViewModel is needed to be passed further by hierarchy. Also updated views names for the better understanding.

Comment: @bodich you are supposed to transform your view data as you pass it down the View struct hierarchy, usually via computed properties passed into View struct inits. You aren't supposed to pass an object down as is.

Comment: @malhal You are welcomed to update your answer code.

Comment: @malhal Don't forget to pass the data getter function in your next example.

Answer (score 11):

Apple engineers have recognised that sheet memory leak is a bug and known issue (r. 115856582) on iOS 17 affecting sheet and fullScreenCover presentation. They proposed the workaround where you can use bridge to UIKit to create your own presentation controllers above your SwiftUI content (preventing the memory retention issue).

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737967?answerId=767599022#767599022

Here is the full code snippet (though it does not support Binding objects, so you can't use something like `.sheet(item: $object)`)

```
import SwiftUI

enum SheetPresenterStyle {
    case sheet
    case popover
    case fullScreenCover
    case detents([UISheetPresentationController.Detent])
}

class SheetWrapperController: UIViewController {
    let style: SheetPresenterStyle
    
    init(style: SheetPresenterStyle) {
        self.style = style
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if case let (.detents(detents)) = style, let sheetController = self.presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController {
            sheetController.detents = detents
            sheetController.prefersGrabberVisible = true
        }
    }
}

struct SheetPresenter<Content>: UIViewRepresentable where Content: View {
    let label: String
    let content: () -> Content
    let style: SheetPresenterStyle
    
    init(_ label: String, style: SheetPresenterStyle, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.label = label
        self.content = content
        self.style = style
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SheetPresenter>) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle(label, for: .normal)
        
        let action = UIAction { _ in
            let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
            hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            let viewController = SheetWrapperController(style: style)
            switch style {
            case .sheet:
                viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
            case .popover:
                viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
                viewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button
            case .fullScreenCover:
                viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            case .detents:
                viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
            }
            
            viewController.addChild(hostingController)
            viewController.view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.topAnchor),
                hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.leadingAnchor),
                hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.trailingAnchor),
                hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.bottomAnchor),
            ])
            
            hostingController.didMove(toParent: viewController)
            
            if let rootVC = button.window?.rootViewController {
                rootVC.present(viewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
        
        button.addAction(action, for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) {}
}

typealias ContentView = ContentViewB

struct ContentViewA: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var showPopover = false
    @State private var showFullScreenCover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present Sheet") { showSheet.toggle() }
            Button("Present Popover") { showPopover.toggle() }
            Button("Present Full Screen Cover") { showFullScreenCover.toggle() }
            
            Text("First")
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                    SheetView()
                }
                .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                    PopoverView()
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showFullScreenCover) {
                    FullScreenCoverView()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViewB: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SheetPresenter("Present Sheet", style: .sheet) {
                SheetView()
            }
            SheetPresenter("Present Popover", style: .popover) {
                PopoverView()
            }
            SheetPresenter("Present Full Screen Cover", style: .fullScreenCover) {
                FullScreenCoverView()
            }
            SheetPresenter("Present Presentation Detents", style: .detents([.medium(), .large()])) {
                PresentationDetentsView()
            }
            Text("First")
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    private let log = LifecycleLogger(name: "SheetView")
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("SheetView")
        Button("Back") { dismiss() }
    }
}

struct PopoverView: View {
    private let log = LifecycleLogger(name: "PopoverView")
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("PopoverView")
        Button("Back") { dismiss() }
    }
}

struct FullScreenCoverView: View {
    private let log = LifecycleLogger(name: "FullScreenCoverView")
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("FullScreenCoverView")
        Button("Back") { dismiss() }
    }
}

struct PresentationDetentsView: View {
    private let log = LifecycleLogger(name: "PresentationDetentsView")
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("PresentationDetentsView")
        Button("Back") { dismiss() }
    }
}

class LifecycleLogger {
    let name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("\(name).init")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("\(name).deinit")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is valid code and I have replicated your observations - `deinit` is not called, and in Instruments the allocated memory grows with each invocation of the sheet.

There is no SwiftUI alternative syntax which would guarantee the `deinit` to be called, so I think you're unlikely to get any further help from StackOverflow users on this topic. Your best bet would be to file a bug with Apple, either via the Apple Feedback app on your Mac or at [feedbackassistant.apple.com](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com). (see [Bug Reporting](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)).

Comment: The question was NOT about using State for class (and it's not a problem, I have tired to explain to each person honestly, the question is totally different from that). Question is only about memory releasing using sheet, I will appreciate if we can focus on it. The suggestion about bug reporting makes sense, thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for sharing all your findings. It helped me a lot!
I did find a workaround, using a very specific combination, that won't require any UIKit. Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SheetModel

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}

class SheetModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    init() {
        print("init", Self.self, Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit", Self.self, Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
    }
}

class ContentModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPresented = false
    @Published var sheet: SheetModel?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = ContentModel()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show sheet") {
            model.sheet = SheetModel()
            model.isPresented = true
        }
        .sheet(
            isPresented: $model.isPresented,
            onDismiss: { model.sheet = nil },
            content: {
                SheetWrapper(model: .init(item: model.sheet!)) { item in
                    SheetView(viewModel: item)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

class SheetWrapperModel<ItemType: AnyObject>: ObservableObject {
    unowned let item: ItemType

    init(item: ItemType) {
        self.item = item
    }
}

struct SheetWrapper<ItemType: AnyObject, ContentType: View>: View {
    @StateObject var model: SheetWrapperModel<ItemType>
    var content: (ItemType) -> ContentType

    var body: some View {
        content(model.item)
    }
}
```

It only works using `.sheet` or `.fullscreenCover` with the `isPresented` binding (doesn't work with the `item` variation) and you cannot rely on SheetView to retain the SheetModel, it must be retained by the presenter (ContentView/ContentModel in this case) because `SheetWrapperModel` has just an `unowned` ref to it.

If you run it on iOS 17 you'll see something like this on the console:

```
init SheetModel 0x00006000033b0d70
deinit SheetModel 0x00006000033b0d70
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You have your property wrappers backwards. StateObject is for initializing and ObservedObject is for passing around

Comment: I wouldn't say it's backwards, but I recognize that It's not recommended to initialize the StateObject like that, outside its View. The whole point here is that the bug only exists for ObservedObject, so if If use a StateObject in the middle, as a bridge, I can dodge the memory leak.

Comment: Backwards… look at the basic documentation, this goes against it in many ways. I get you are seeing what you want but I believe it is only because of the nature of ObservedObject and the reason why it is different from StateObject.

Comment: The bug is fixed though I can't reproduce

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just "`boolify`" the optional item binding? Then use `isPresented:..` variant of the sheet. 
Here is how to `boolify` the item:

```
extension Binding {    
  static func boolify<T: Any>(_ binding: Binding<T?>) -> Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool> {
      binding.wrappedValue != nil
    } set: { newValue in
      guard !newValue else {
        assertionFailure("only false is valid")
        return
      }
      binding.wrappedValue = nil
    }
  }
}
```

I think that will not cause the leak.

Comment: Because I've tried to pass the class through Binding, and it is not causing the memory leak only if I capture weak reference inside the Binding getter and setter. So your example is not relevant and causing memory leaks. Binding itself can't do any magic. PS: Apple finally fixed this bug in iOS 17.2. So, instead of workarounds, users on 17...17.1 will just have memory leaks.

Comment: i think binding can do the magic because then you use totally other sheet function, I think the leak is in this sheet(item: function and not in the binding itself

Comment: I never said the leak is in Binding. It's in the sheet, and your binding can't help because it's just wrapping the strong reference. Anyway, this bug was fixed by Apple already, so we don't need to find any workarounds anymore.

Answer (score -3):

*(I've updated my answer so all previous comments are no longer relevant and should be deleted when you have a spare minute thanks).*

There are a couple of major issues with this SwiftUI code. The first is the view model object, in SwiftUI the view struct hierarchy is designed to hold the view data so it is essentially a view model already. The second is `@State` is designed to only work with value types, not objects because (as you experienced) they are not set to `nil` when no longer required thus an object would never be released. This is not an issue for value types on the memory stack, but for objects on the heap yes it's a big problem.

You would be better not to use objects in this case, but if you really want to, you can work around the issue by implementing your own release as follows:

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @State var sheetConfig = SheetConfig()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            sheetConfig.present()
        } label: {
            Text("Navigate")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetConfig.isPresented) {
            Color.yellow
        }
    }
}

struct SheetConfig {
    var object: SheetVM?
    
    var isPresented: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if !isPresented {
                object = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    mutating func present() {
        object = SheetVM()
        isPresented = true
    }
}

// Health warning, don't try to implement view models using Combine's ObservableObject and instead learn the View struct for your view data.
final class SheetVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var title: String = "Title"
    
    init() {
        print("SheetVM init")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("... SheetVM deinit")
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a SIMPLIFIED example. I will not upload whole project here. of course I use that ViewModel class inside the sheet. I don't need to change that class to struct, what's the sense of your suggestion? I need a class!

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is a view model already so you don't need a class. Also since this is Swift you should prefer structs to classes in general.

Comment: Lol. I need a class here. I did not ask if I need to use struct. Question is about memory releasing using sheet, I will appreciate if we can focus on it.

Comment: `@State` is already backed by a class, I'm interested to know why you need another one.

Comment: Because the View which I have put inside the sheet (and obviously did not add in this example because it's not related to a question) receives ObservableObject as a parameter and has @ObservedObject property. I thought it's obvious I will pass sheetVM further. Definitely not to just show Color.yellow inside the sheet. Now ask "Why do you need  ObservedObject in the view, Apple tells us to not use classes inside views...". Oh wait, Apple does not tell us that, they even created ObservedObject property wrapper specifically to use in Views.

Comment: Now you can see this answer with a lot of links where other people are facing this exact issue. Without "this is because of you are using class in State". It's a bug which is multiple times reported to Apple and Apple engineers just say thank you for reports, not saying to just not use classes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77235312/7147231

Comment: I wouldn't say its a bug, if it was they would have fixed it by now. They made a decision to undo the what they did in the first beta to make the State init an autoclosure probably because it broke value semantics which are more important to SwiftUI. It's surprising they haven't just added a new `@StateObservable` but perhaps they don't want to encourage peoples' use of classes when they should really be learning the `View` struct for their view data and `.task` for their async view data. `@Observable` is designed for model data anyway, so no observable for view state is needed.

Comment: What are you talking about? I never said they have any bug with State. They made a bug with sheet and fullScreenCover.

Comment: Show me where there is any class under the State wrapper in this case. You don't even try to understand, neither the problem nor the SwiftUI. Why are you telling me about the State init if I update it from button, I don't initialise it each time in my example, it was initialised only once on SheetView implicit init. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153299/swiftui-view-leaks-in-ios-17

Comment: State is a DynamicProperty backed by a reference type. It doesn't matter that you wrapped your reference type in a value type. You're on the wrong track here, remove your VM reference type and use the View struct as it's designed.

Comment: Apple created `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject` specially for SwiftUI views. You can learn how to use these property wrappers in apple docs.

Comment: Recently you said that `@State` strictly must not contain any reference type behind the value type wrapper. You said that Optional enum usage is wrong when it contains class inside. Now you put class inside the struct. Can you explain the difference, why your class inside struct is correct while class inside enum is forbidden by your statement?

Comment: I've updated the code in my question in accordance with my recent explanation. `SheetVM` must be initialised outside of the sheet and passed there for the inner `SheetView` (updated naming). You can update your code in the answer now.

Comment: You said `they are not set to nil when no longer required thus an object would never be released ` which is wrong. Without sheet capturing it in iOS 17, or with sheet in iOS <17 when you set State to nil, object which lays inside the State is released absolutely fine. You can learn what is Optional in Apple docs, it is a enum which is a value type.